# Toast Message Again

Tags: php

My toast message didnt appear at all. Other than that the new problem came up after i switch position of toast message from bottom to top at page2.

> **Warning**: Undefined array key "success_message" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\pta\dashboarduser\insert\kemahiran.php** on line **17**

```
- page1.php
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.6.5/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.6.5/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
</html>
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'config.php';
    
    if (isset($_SESSION['id_pensyarah'])) {
        $idpensyarah = $_SESSION['id_pensyarah'];
    
        if (isset($_POST['insertakademik'])) {
            $tahun = $_POST['tahunakademik'];
            $pencapaian = $_POST['pencapaianakademik'];
            $id_institusi = $_POST['id_institusi'];
            $institusi_baharu = $_POST['institusiakademikbaharu'];

            if ($institusi_baharu == null) {
                // Insert into akademik table directly using the selected id_institusi
                $sql1 = "INSERT INTO akademik (tahun, pencapaian, id_pensyarah, id_institusi) VALUES ('$tahun', '$pencapaian', '$idpensyarah', '$id_institusi')";
                $execute1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

                if ($execute1) {
                    $_SESSION['success_message'] = "Tambah Data Kelayakan Akademik dan Ikhtisas";
                    $_SESSION['redirect_token'] = uniqid();
                    header('Location: .././kemahiran.php');
                } else {
                    echo 'Error execute1 data: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
                }
            } else {
                // Insert the new institution into institusi table first
                $sql2 = "INSERT INTO institusi (institusi) VALUES ('$institusi_baharu')";
                $execute2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
            
                if ($execute2) {
                    // Get the last inserted ID and insert into akademik table
                    $new_id_institusi = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO akademik (tahun, pencapaian, id_pensyarah, id_institusi) VALUES ('$tahun', '$pencapaian', '$idpensyarah', '$new_id_institusi')";
                    $execute3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);

                    if ($execute3) {
                        $_SESSION['success_message'] = "Tambah Data Kelayakan Akademik dan Ikhtisas";
                        header('Location: .././kemahiran.php');
                    } else {
                        echo 'Error execute3 data: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
                    }
                } else {
                    echo 'Error execute2 data: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    
    
?>

 - clear_session.php

    <?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['success_message']);
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_token']);
    ?>

- page2.php

    <?php
        session_start();
        include "config.php";
    
        if (isset($_SESSION['success_message']) && isset($_SESSION['redirect_token'])) {
                
            unset($_SESSION['success_message']);
            unset($_SESSION['redirect_token']);
    
            echo "<script>
                Swal.fire({
                    position: 'top-end',
                    toast: true,
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: '" . $_SESSION['success_message'] . "',
                    text: 'Berjaya!',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 3000,
                    timerProgressBar: true,
                    backgroundColor: '#28a745',
                    titleColor: '#fff',
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    
                    });
                });
            </script>";
        }
    
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM institusi");
        $result2 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM institusi");
    
        $result3 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM jawatan");
        $result4 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM jawatan");
    
        $result5 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM kategoripelajaran");
    
        $id_pensyarah = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['id_pensyarah']);
        $result6 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM pensyarah WHERE id_pensyarah = '$id_pensyarah'");
    
        
    ?>
```

i expect the toast message will show after i insert data akademik at page2.php

Comment: You write unset($_SESSION['success_message']) and then two lines later you try to use the values you've just removed. Unset the Session value _after_ you've finished using it

Comment: P.s. your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks and basic sql syntax issues. you must use prepared statements and parameters instead of adding data directly into sql strings. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement for the correct approach. Not sure where you learned to write it the way you've shown here but unfortunately they taught you some bad habits

Answer (score 0):

```
// Modify this line - $_SESSION['success_message'] This param is undfined, if the query is not executed , So add this line in else condition also.`enter code here`

if ($execute3) {
    $_SESSION['success_message'] = "Tambah Data Kelayakan Akademik dan Ikhtisas";
    header('Location: .././kemahiran.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['success_message'] = mysqli_error($conn);
    
}
```